C# Windows Form App (.Net) ListView: Change the Color of the "empty space" at the end if the ListView Header
You've successfully changed the color of a ListView's header and everything else of the ListView.
However, i'm struggling to find a solution to change the color of the header's "empty space" at the end of the header.
Whatever i try, this area seems to be untouched on any "DrawListView" Event Handlers.
Maybe anyone got a solution for this?
I've tried everything in the DrawListViewColumnHeaderEventHandler, such as:
e.Graphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.Black, e.Bounds);

also anything from:
Change the background color of Winform ListView headers
how to change the color of the list items in list view
and also many other methods all around the Internet i've found!
But yet the "empty space" remains unaffected!

https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/4243/Customizing-the-header-control-in-a-ListView#:~:text=flag%20%2D%20owner%2Ddraw.-,HeaderControl%20class,-The%20HeaderControl%20class

oh, that's nice!
totally missed this
thank you!
